# REGEX pattern to exlude specific string

Tags: python

I have a string that have this format:

```
some text <br>septembar 1989<br>
```

And I'm using this regex find the month and year part

```
<br/?>(?!=b\.)(.*?\b\d{4}\b)
```

and I get what i want-`septembar 1989`

However, I now have situation when `<br>` is inserted

```
<br>some text <br>septembar 1989<br>
```

result: `some text <br>septembar 1989`

Can you suggest how to modify my existing pattern to support both cases? I guess I need somehow to exlude `<br>` from matching in `.*?`

Comment: Your pattern doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<br/?>([^<]+)\d{4}
```

`[^<]` means match anything except an opening tag which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

ss = 'dfgqeg<br>some text <br>septembar 1989<br>'

reg = re.compile('<br(?: /)?>'
                 '(?!.+?<br(?: /)?>.+?<br(?: /)?>)'
                 '(.+?\d{4})'
                 '<br(?: /)?>')

print reg.search(ss).group(1)
```

.

- `'<br(?: /)?>'` catches `<br>` and `<br />` occurrences

.

- `'(?!.+?<br(?: /)?>.+?<br(?: /)?>)'` is a look-ahead assertion,
  it verifies that after the position where it starts in the analyzed text, there isn't the suite of characters described as a succession of :

  - `.+?`  any kind of characters, but the `?` orders that this portion must stop as soon as `<br>` or `<br />` is encountered
  - `<br>` or `<br />`
  - again any kind of characters stopping before `<br>` or `<br />`
  - `<br>` or `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

I written a simple code, may be you find helpful unto some extend:

```
import re
def getDate(str):
 m = re.match("[\<br>]*[\w\s]*\<br>([\w\s]*[12][0-9]{3})",str);
 return m.group(1)

print getDate("some text <br>dec 1989<br>");
print getDate("<br> some text <br>septembar 1989<br>");
print getDate("grijesh chuahan <br>feb 2009<br>");
```

Output:

```
dec 1989
septembar 1989
feb 2009
```